# Предложение по использованию метки grid-css / css-grid

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, создание-метки

В CSS набирает популярность использование `display: grid`, а значит, что скоро всех любителей ветки CSS ждет обилие вопросов по этой теме. Специально для этого типа вопросов я создал метку [grid-css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid-css), которая будет аналогом метки [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) и позволит помечать ей специфические вопросы.

У нас есть готовая метка [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid), но она содержит очень общие вопросы из разных языков программирования/систем. Подозреваю, что вопросы по теме `display: grid` часто будут помечаться этой меткой. Также, вероятно, нас ждет *создание* подобных меток, вроде [display-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display-grid), [grid-layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid-layout) и т. д.

Именно в связи с этим у меня образовалось предложение — помечать уже готовой меткой [grid-css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid-css) вопросы такого типа и выпиливать из них безликую метку [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid) или другие метки, которые будут создаваться.

### Почему [grid-css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid-css), а не [css-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid)?

При создании метки исходил из предполагаемого поведения пользователей, которые первым делом напишут **grid**, а потом выберут первую попавшуюся метку, которая начинается на **grid**

---

### В результате:

Принято решение использовать метку [css-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid) для пометки вопросов по этой тематике, как более семантично верную, чем [grid-css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid-css). Прошу всех принять к сведению :-)

Comment: "grid-css, которая будет аналогом метки flexbox "  — а между ними разница-то есть?

Comment: @NickVolynkin конечно же есть. Это два совершенно разных механизма.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ок, я на всякий случай.

Answer (score 4):

Обычно «родовое» понятие ставят первым, например [android-sdk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk), [android-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio). Поэтому *если эта метка вообще нужна*, то лучше использовать [css-grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid).

> предполагаемого поведения пользователей, которые первым делом напишут **grid**, а потом выберут первую попавшуюся метку, которая начинается на **grid**

<s>Первая попавшаяся метка будет [grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid).</s>

Оказывается, поиск устроен умнее:

[image]

---

Насчёт того, нужна или не нужна, мнения не имею, т.к. не разбираюсь в CSS.

Comment: Я подумал об этом в самом начале, но в последствии при создании метки исходил из возможного поведения пользователей, которые первым делом напишут **grid**, а потом выберут первую попавшуюся метку, которая начинается на **grid**.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko ответил правкой.

Comment: Может удалить метку [tag:grid]? В ней в куче и гриды из верстки, и датагриды из всевозможных ui-фреймворков для JS, C# и даже Delphi.

Comment: @Nofate согласен, метка неоднозначная. Хорошо бы позаменять на более релевантные.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko не хотите ли пробежаться по [tag:grid] и порасставлять более подходящие метки? А саму метку [tag:grid] мы можем потом засинонимизировать к [tag:css-grid]. Не факт, что нужно синонимизировать, но обдумать стоит.

Comment: Тут просится что-то типа [tag:data-grid] и [tag:layout-grid]. Еще ведь бывают в природе [tag:computation-grid] или [tag:grid-computing].

Comment: @NickVolynkin если в вопросе уже есть метки [tag:CSS], [tag:CSS3], то когда пользователь вводит **grid**, то система первым делом подсунет безликий **grid**, а следом, если будет достаточно ассоциаций с [tag:CSS] будет [tag:grid-css], разве нет?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko а вот даже не знаю, есть ли там какая-то умная сортировка меток по релевантности.

Comment: @NickVolynkin расставлять по всей метке **grid** более подходящие мне, боюсь, не хватит компетенции, потому что там мешанина из разных языков. конкретно по модулю *css grid* нашел только один вопрос пока что.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko думаю, [вы зря беспокоитесь](http://i.imgur.com/shRcu1q.png). Там сортировка по количеству вопросов. [tag:grid] займёт в лучшем случае одну клеточку, хотя похоже, что его скоро выпилят.

Comment: ага, тогда вообще без вопросов. сам изначально хотел сделать именно **css-grid**. как тогда теперь быть с созданной меткой и написанным описанием к ней?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko а с ними уже всё хорошо, проверьте )

Comment: @D-side о, я и не замечал, что там такой удобный поиск.

Comment: @NickVolynkin о, спасибо, я доволен )

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko вы всё равно пробегитесь по [tag:grid] и разметьте хотя бы те вопросы, в которых разбираетесь. А то сколько обсуждения, а метка на одном вопросе. ))